# What are the possible reasons for slow hard disks?

Tags: hard-drive, speed

**WARNING: This question arose from a buggy test software. After its fixing, the time required to copy a file, large 3.5 Gb, is best estimate between 45 and 60 sec, on heavy load. I'm sorry for disturbing you.**

I have just assembled my new PC and I'm observing troubles with its five brand new hard disks.  They are all extremely slow: it takes more than a minute to complete a command like

```
copy d:\file1 d:\file2
```

where file is 1.5 Mb large. HD are completely void, tested both just a minute and dozens of hours after boot completion and while no other program is running.

I have read [Hard disk suddenly extremely slow](https://superuser.com/questions/1152901/hard-disk-suddenly-extremely-slow), but it seems unlikely that all my disks are defective and DOA.

I have no idea of the possible reason; can you please provide any advice?

Please, see the screenshots below.

- Mother board: omissis (supports SATA III)
- Hard disks: omissis
- Western Digital Data Lifeguard diagnostics short test: each passed after a few minutes
- Western Digital Data Lifeguard diagnostics long test: each passed after 6 hours
- Krystal Disk Info 7.9.3 x64 report: all healthy
- OS: Windows 10.0.14393 booted from Hiren’s BootCD PE (Preinstallation Environment)
- metal scratching sound: none
- data partition: GPT
- File system: NTFS

[image: test screenshoots]

Comment: How long did you wait after boot? Windows and background programs continue to do a lot of activity in the background after it reaches the point where you can start doing things. Actions can be very slow for awhile.

Comment: In a test I have waited approximately 40 hours.

Comment: Try starting in safe mode or clean mode to rule out the effect of anything else that might be running in the background.  In fact, rule out Hiren's as the problem by doing as close a test as you can booting normally.

Comment: Do you mean that I should install the SO on an hard disk ?

Comment: I wasn't referring to installing anything, I'm suggesting to rule out a few potential causes.  One is your measurement tool.  Make sure it isn't giving you flaky results  or causing them when you don't actually have a problem.  Also, rule out other potential background activity.  Do a clean boot or boot into safe mode; just a barebones startup with no Internet, no antivirus, no applications, nothing but the bare minimum needed to operate.  Do some manual data transfer tests to see if you're in the same ballpark as what you've been seeing.  If so, you've narrowed it to hardware.  (Cont'd)

Comment: I would also boot into a Linux live session and run similar manual tests.  That will rule out anything related to Windows or drivers.  If you still get very slow performance, it has to be hardware.

Comment: Ok, thanks !! I'm going to follow all your hints. I will keep you up to date.

Comment: Saw the edit.  Does this mean you no longer have a problem?  If so, great!  Always nice to have a happy ending to a problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP states that there wasn't actually a problem, just bad info from the test software.